# code page setting in visual studio setup project

Tags: windows, installation, setup-project, setup-deployment, codepages

I have this code page warming when I build our setup project.
[image]

After I set correct code page and languageid to:
[image]

It fails on build:
[image]

Some text can not be displayed correctly if I don't solve this warming.
[image]

How can I solve this code page error?

Comment: What tool are you using? It appears that you might be manually setting values in a Visual Studio setup project file, and the not supported.

Comment: I use Visual Studio, I have figure out it is a limit of Visual Studio setup project, it does not support languages other than these:1252 (Neutral, English, French, German, Italian, and Spanish), 936 (Chinese (Simplified)), 950 (Chinese (Traditional)), 932 (Japanese), and 949 (Korean).    

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcx25hzz(v=vs.100).aspx